# May detect beacons late

Tags: ibeacon-android

The time to detect beacons shifts.

For example, even if you are near a beacon at 17:00, it appears to be in didRangeBeaconsInRegion at 18:00.

However, it cannot be reproduced.

Have you ever noticed a beacon detection time that has been off by more than an hour?

````
    onCreate()
    ```
            g_beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
            g_beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
            g_beaconManager.bind(this);
            g_beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(4000);
            g_region = new Region("iBeacon", null, null, null);
    ```

    g_beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    ```
            g_beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> Beacons, Region region) {

                    String l_broadcasetMessage = " 受信ビーコンのNoと距離：\n";

                    Beacon lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance = null;

                    Log.d("Beacon" , "addRangeNotifier Success!!");

                    // 検出したビーコンの情報を全部Logに書き出す
                    for (Beacon beacon : Beacons) {

                        if (lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance == null)
                        {
                            lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance = beacon;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // 現在認識しているビーコンよりも距離が近いビーコンを検知すれば、ステータス更新
                            if (lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance.getDistance() > beacon.getDistance())
                            {
                                lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance = beacon;
                            }
                        }

                        // ログの出力
                        Log.d("Beacon", "UUID:" + beacon.getId1() + ", major:" + beacon.getId2()
                                + ", minor:" + beacon.getId3() + ", Distance:" + beacon.getDistance()
                                + ",RSSI" + beacon.getRssi());
                    }

                    g_most_Distance_Beacon = lBeacon_Most_Near_Distance;
                }
            });

```
````

Comment: Is the code shown in an Activity, a background service or a foreground service?   Do you see delays when the app is in the foreground or the background?  Is the screen on or off?  Is the phone motionless for a long period of time? On what phone model and OS version do you see the behavior?

Comment: foreground service.  App is in the background.  The smartphone is Fujitsu arrows M03. OS is 5.0.  While in the background, only one out of 50 had problems.  the phone motionless for a long period of time.